# Criar novo PDF a partir de PDF existente com PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf, header, footer

Estou com um projeto que eu preciso adicionar cabeçalho/rodapé/marca d'água, dinamicamente em arquivos PDF existentes, através da linguagem PHP.

Já pesquisei bastante e ainda não encontrei uma forma de fazer isto.

É possível editar PDFs existentes em PHP e adicionar informações?

Ou ainda, seria possível criar um novo PDF, através de um já existente, e assim poder editar o conteúdo desse novo PDF?

Uma outra forma que pensei seria transformar o PDF existente em HTML e ai transformar esse HTML em um novo PDF com o cabeçalho/rodapé/marca d'água.

Comment: São muitas perguntas em uma só pergunta, mas tudo bem. Bem, quero te dizer que 60% do que você **deseja** não é possível. Existem várias classes PHP que lidam com PDFs.  Você consegue **criar** PDF, mas editar PDF talvez seja um longo caminho. Depende muito do que significa editar pdf. Criar um rodapé por exemplo, poderia ser relativamente fácil, mas alterar um texto no pdf, vai depender de muitos fatores, começando pela forma que esse PDF foi criado. Veja esse [exemplo](https://rubayeet.wordpress.com/2010/02/05/modifying-pdf-files-with-php/)

Comment: Tambem não sei se será possivel, mas tenta ver o mPDF https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf

Comment: Se não forem muito complexos, talvez o mais rápido seja simular/recriar esses pdfs existentes em HTML...

Comment: Sim @brasofilo, são várias as possibilidades, só que precisa ficar mais claro o que significa **editar um pdf**.

Comment: @durtto, imagino que não tem muito mistério, significa fazer o que o Acrobat Pro ou Nitro PDF fazem: abrir um PDF e colar/remover elementos e gravar um novo. Não acho que são "muitas perguntas em uma só", pra mim está claro: como abrir um PDF existente, colar um header e footer, gravar um PDF novo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510117/using-fpdf-to-modify-existing-pdf-in-php

Comment: Pessoal, consegui resolver o meu problema com o que foi postado pelo @durtto utilizando as bibliotecas FPDF e FPDI. Obrigado a todos!
Exemplo: https://rubayeet.wordpress.com/2010/02/05/modifying-pdf-files-with-php/

Comment: O link do @Daniel Omine também me ajudou! Obrigado!

Comment: Isso é muito bom. Willian, então agora vou transformar meu comentário em resposta e se você achar que foi uma resposta para a sua pergunta, marque-a como aceita. Foi um prazer ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

São muitas perguntas em uma só pergunta, mas tudo bem. Bem, quero te dizer que 60% do que você deseja não é possível. Existem várias classes PHP que lidam com PDFs. Você consegue criar PDF, mas editar PDF talvez seja um longo caminho. **`Depende muito do que significa editar pdf`**. Criar um rodapé por exemplo, poderia ser relativamente fácil, mas alterar um texto no pdf, vai depender de muitos fatores, começando pela forma que esse PDF foi criado. Veja esse [exemplo](https://rubayeet.wordpress.com/2010/02/05/modifying-pdf-files-with-php/)